# Chart.js: Bar chart shows labels, not data

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

I want to draw a bar plot with chart.js using this code (very simple):

```
    this.plotEnergy = new Chart($('#plotEnergy'),
        {
            type: 'bar',
            animation: false,
            data:
                {
                    labels: ["aaa", "bbb"],
                    datasets: [ {
                        label: "ijoij",
                        backgroundColor: '#000000',
                        data: [2000, 2300]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "ijooijojij",
                        backgroundColor: '#FF00FF',
                        data: [1500, 2500]
                    }, 
                ]
                },
            options:
                {
                     tooltips:
                    {
                        mode: 'index',
                        intersect: false
                    },
                    title:
                        {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Generated energy'
                        },
                    responsive: true,
                    scales:
                        {
                            xAxes: [
                                {
                                    stacked: 'false',
                                    position: 'bottom',
                                }],
                            yAxes: [
                                {
                                    stacked: false,
                                    scaleLabel:
                                        {
                                            display: true,
                                            labelString: 'Energy [kWh]'
                                        },
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                    }
                                }]
                        }
                }


        });
```

But I get this: The labels are showed correctly, even the y-axis range is correct. But the bars don't show up. I can click on the legends items to make the corresponding data disappear and the y-axis range would adapt correctly.

[image]

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Your options are causing issues there, here is a sample I took from your data and generated this jsbin: https://jsbin.com/jopudiwema/1/edit?html,css,js,output feel free to change the options accordingly to what you need and you'll be fine.

Comment: Oh I see, it's the x-axis option "stacked: false" which was causing an issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad that you found out.